Why does my boost.asio server accept data from host but not from vm?
I am new to Boost.asio and C++. I am trying to create a simple program which listens on a certain port for data and displays that data on the terminal. When the simple server (my C++, boost.asio code) is running and I go to the terminal on my computer (Mac) and use the nc command it connects without a problem. The problem is when I try to connect to the program using nc from an Ubuntu VM on VirtualBox, the program does not receive any data. Since the TCP acceptor is 0.0.0.0 I don't understand why my terminal on host will connect to the program's listening port but the VM won't connect to program's listening port. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Echo "hello" | nc (ip address) (port) on Terminal displays hello in program command line but running this command on VM doesn't display in program command line
For extra info running above command from the VM to a listening port on host Terminal works just fine, so the VM can connect to my computer
Edit: I'm not using a fixed IP because when I did that I got error "Address already in use [system:48 at /usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/reactive_socket_service.hpp:161:33 in function 'bind']". When I first ran it it would work, but after that always give me this error.
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/system/error_code.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main() {
    try {
        boost::asio::io_context io_context;


        tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address_v4::any(), 0);
        tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_context, endpoint);

        tcp::endpoint local_endpoint = acceptor.local_endpoint();
        unsigned short port = local_endpoint.port();

        std::cout << "Listening for connections on port " << port << "..." << std::endl;

        while (true) {
            tcp::socket socket(io_context);
            boost::system::error_code ec;

 
            acceptor.accept(socket, ec);

            if (ec) {
                std::cerr << "Connection rejected: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                continue; 
            }

            std::cout << "Connection accepted from " << socket.remote_endpoint() << std::endl;

            std::string data;

            while (true) {
                char buf[1024];
                boost::system::error_code error;
                size_t len = socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf), error);

                if (error == boost::asio::error::eof) {

                    break;
                } else if (error) {
                    std::cerr << "Error during read: " << error.message() << std::endl;
                    break;
                }

                data.append(buf, len);
                std::cout.write(buf, len);
                std::cout.flush();
            }

            std::cout << "\nConnection closed." << std::endl;

            boost::system::error_code ignored_ec;
            socket.shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_both, ignored_ec);
            socket.close(ignored_ec);
            break;
        }

        acceptor.close();
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}


Is there a firewall interfering? You might need to allow traffic on that port, specifically from the source host (vm). This is a lot easier to do when the port is fixed, see e.g. https://www.coursera.org/articles/ephemeral-ports

Sounds more like a virtual box problem than a programming problem. How have you configured the networking? Which IP address are you trying to connect to?

@AlanBirtles I think my networking is okay. My VM is using a Bridged network so that it can connect to the host, and it does so just fine, but specifically won't connect to my "server". I didn't know if this was a Boost.asio issue since everything else seems fine. Host to server GOOD, VM to Host GOOD, VM to server BAD. Definitely a bit confused haha.

@sehe  I disabled the firewall when it didn't work, and it still doesn't work ha. Funny thing is VM connects to a listening port from Mac Terminal, but not to my program so I don't think it's a firewall issue. I am not using a fixed port in code because when I used any fix port I got error: Address already in use [system:48 at /usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/reactive_socket_service.hpp:161:33 in function 'bind']

That just means you're choosing a pretty that's not available. Try something else? 7878 or 14253

@sehe I've tried a variety of ports and I still get the same error after the first try. Server only works when it can choose the port but only accepts connections from host not VM.

Well, at this rate it's not really a programming question. Consider https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/, https://serverfault.com/ or similar

@sehe Sorry to bother again but I forgot to mention doing similar code in Python actually worked. The VM could connect to listening port. Since Python is higher-level, could it mean my C++ code isn't robust enough and is missing something?

I’ve looked at the code and would not do anything differently. Though I might initialize the endpoint as tcp::endpoint{{}, 7878} but the way I checked it it did the same bind (0.0.0.0:7878). You could try that.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
